# getGeneratedKeys() don't work when a SELECT query is before the insert query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

`preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()` works fine when the query is only a single INSERT MySQL statement, but if you have multiple statements in the query it won't return gernerated IDs, i.e: `test` has (ID (PK, auto_increment), Name, Loan) columns:

```
        sqlQuery = "SET @Loan = (SELECT Loan FROM customers WHERE CID = 4);"
                + "INSERT INTO test(Name, Loan) VALUES('jihad', @Loan);";
        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        st.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("Generated ID: "+ id);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this answer will help fix your problem, but it is possible to write your insert as a single statement:

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Loan) ";
sqlQuery += "SELECT 'jihad', (SELECT Loan FROM customers WHERE CID = 4)";

PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
st.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives without a variable:

```
-- "INSERT INTO test(Name, Loan) VALUES('jihad', (SELECT Loan FROM customers WHERE CID = 4))"
"INSERT INTO test(Name, Loan) SELECT 'jihad', Loan FROM customers WHERE CID = 4"
```

As the driver does not seem to handle multiple statement okay. You might also try to remove the last semi-colon `;`.

***P.S.***
*As Tim Biegeleisen commented the first version does not work on MySQL, his answer provides yet another variant.*

Comment: [Your first version does not work on MySQL](https://rextester.com/XEGT77158).  But it might work on Oracle.